# Assign value to NSUInteger in object after init

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinteger, nsuinteger

I have a subclass of NSObject. In this class I have an NSUInteger declared like this:

```
@interface Deck : NSObject

- (id)initDecks:(NSUInteger)decks;
- (Card *)drawCard;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger drawnCards;
```

In my implementation file, I have the following code:

```
#import "Deck.h"

@implementation Deck

- (id)initDecks:(NSUInteger)decks {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.drawnCards = 1;
    }

    return self;
}

- (BJCard *)drawCard {
    self.drawnCards++;
    return nil;
}
```

The number assigned to the NSUInteger (drawnCards) in the init method is set correctly, however, I am not able to change it later. I get no warnings or crashes in Xcode, but the number remains unchangeable. I have tried to do self.drawnCards++ and self.drawnCards = 10 etc, but nothing works. Any idea what might be wrong with my code? I am checking the value with:

```
NSLog(@"Value: %tu", self.drawnCards);
```

Comment: There's no reason that `self.drawnCards = 10;` should not change the value. Please create a [minimal, runnable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem here is the objectiveC dot syntax. Because you are doing `.` with an object this is the equivalent to doing `[self drawnCards]++` method call. The result of the method is incremented, not the drawnCards ivar. To do what you want you'll either need to do `_drawnCards++` (access the iVar directly), or you'll need to do `[self setDrawnCards:self.drawnCards++]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both ways, unfortunately, it only returns the initial value.

Comment: In which case it's likely something more obvious like you're not calling the `NSLog` on the same object that you're incrementing the variable. To find the problem we'd need to see more of the code managing the Deck object.

Comment: Ahh, a reset of simulator and cleaning the build folder did the magic, combined with your solution. Thanks :)